# Access object properties by dynamically generating their names from somewhere else(enum)

Tags: c#, class, properties, enums

I am trying to do some optimization on my code. I have an `enum`:

```
enum Months { Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec }
```

and the following code with an object of a ready made class:

```
oi.Jan = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[0]), 2).ToString();
oi.Feb = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[1]), 2).ToString();
oi.Mar = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[2]), 2).ToString();
oi.Apr = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[3]), 2).ToString();
oi.May = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[4]), 2).ToString();
oi.Jun = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[5]), 2).ToString();
oi.Jul = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[6]), 2).ToString();
oi.Aug = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[7]), 2).ToString();
oi.Sep = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[8]), 2).ToString();
oi.Oct = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[9]), 2).ToString();
oi.Nov = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[10]), 2).ToString();
oi.Dec = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[11]), 2).ToString();
```

I'm trying to something do like this(pseudo code):

```
oi.[Months[i]] = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(adjAllocation[0]), 2).ToString();
```

I can't just put an array in the class I am making an object from. I need the properties to be strings for the ready made class I am calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not optimization but an attempt of simplification. Reflection can do this, but seems not simplified at all:

```
public enum Months {
    Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec
}

public partial class SomeClass {
    public String Jan { get; set; }
    public String Feb { get; set; }
    public String Mar { get; set; }
    public String Apr { get; set; }
    public String May { get; set; }
    public String Jun { get; set; }
    public String Jul { get; set; }
    public String Aug { get; set; }
    public String Sep { get; set; }
    public String Oct { get; set; }
    public String Nov { get; set; }
    public String Dec { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(IConvertible[] array) {
        var count=(
            from Months month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Months))
            let index=(int)month
            where index<array.Length
            select
                typeof(SomeClass).InvokeMember(
                    Enum.GetName(typeof(Months), month),
                    BindingFlags.SetProperty|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public,
                    default(Binder), this,
                    new object[] { Math.Round(array[index].ToDecimal(null), 2).ToString() }
                    )
            ).Count();
    }
}
```

If the array `adjAllocation` can be converted to decimal, then it would be an array of `IConvertible`. So pass it to the constructor of `SomeClass`, you are done.

Comment: How would you simplify it yourself?

Comment: @AngelicCore: Sorry, I don't understand your comment .. would you describe some more about what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry about that,
I mean if you were me, how would you go about simplifying the code up there?
Personally i wish to use an array indexer or something similar instead of having to write one line for each month. Problem is the function which receives objects of this class can't read arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There is `System.Enum`-class which provides auxilliary methods to support working with `enum`s.
For example, there is `Enum.GetName`-method to access a specific value. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx):

```
using System;

public class GetNameTest {
    enum Colors { Red, Green, Blue, Yellow };
    enum Styles { Plaid, Striped, Tartan, Corduroy };

    public static void Main() {

        Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Colors Enum is {0}", Enum.GetName(typeof(Colors), 3));
    Console.WriteLine("The 4th value of the Styles Enum is {0}", Enum.Get.   Name(typeof(Styles), 3));
    }
}
// The example displays the following output: 
//       The 4th value of the Colors Enum is Yellow 
//       The 4th value of the Styles Enum is Corduroy
```

Comment: Can i use the name to access a property with the same name from an obj? like above:
A.Jan
A.Feb
A.Mar

can i dynamically give the property name?

Comment: Check the other methods in `System.Enum`, you can't use the enum like an array, though.

Comment: The `GetName`-method returns a `string`, so if you can use a `string` in your desired position, then yes.